# JMeter - Uploaded file count issue

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have one web application where I want to upload the files and test the load and performance of the file upload functionality. The uploaded files are displaying with its count on my web page under test. I have recorded the process using JMeter. Now I am running the same script it is showing successful run of the script in results but the count of files is not getting increased.
It's not a functional testing but JMeter is verifying the successful file upload then it should show the number of file increased everytime as file upload script run is successful.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter marks [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as passed or failed depending on the [HTTP Response Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), if it's below [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) - it will be successful.

So my expectation is that your test silently fails somewhere somehow, i.e. it returns [status code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) but there is an error message somewhere in the response body.

So inspect requests and responses details using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and ensure that your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing and fix the Sampler(s) which are sending incorrect requests. You can also add [Response Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to explicitly check that response contains anticipated data and/or doesn't contain any error messages.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I have already checked that but no error found anywhere.